# TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

I'm learning Flask and i can't make my form working. The form should get the name of user and print it on the same page

Form:

```
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField(
        'What is your name?',
        validators=[Length(min = 4, max = 25), Required])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

Views:

```
@app.route('/login/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    name = None
    formi = LoginForm()
    if formi.validate_on_submit():
        name = formi.name.data
        formi.name.data = ''
    return render_template('LoginForm.html', formi = formi, name = name)
```

Template:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="login">
{{ formi.hidden_tag() }}
<p>Enter your nickname</p>
{{ formi.name(size=25) }}
<input type="submit" value="Submit form">
</form>
```

Error:

```
TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Comment: Try to instantiate a `Required` validator: `Required()`.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the if the spelling is right > " formi"

```
@app.route('/login/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    name = None
    **formi** = LoginForm()
    if formi.validate_on_submit():
        name = formi.name.data
        formi.name.data = ''
    return render_template('LoginForm.html', formi = formi, name = name)
```